# Solve ODE with separating variables after taking the root?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f=f(x)$ and $a,b$ constants. How can I solve the differential equation:
$$
(f')^2=a^2f^2+b^2?
$$

Can I do this by first writing
$$
f'=\sqrt{a^2f^2+b^2}
$$
and then separating variables, i.e.
$$
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2f^2+b^2}}\, df=\int\, dx
$$
which gives
$$
\dfrac{\ln\left(\left|b\sqrt{a^2f^2+b^2}+a\left|b\right|f\right|\right)}{a}=x+C
$$
and therefore, after some calculations,
$$
f=\frac{b}{a}\sinh(ax)?
$$

Comment: Where did the dependence on $C$ go?

Comment: You're also missing $f'=-\sqrt{a^2f^2+b^2}$